# Django error import ProhibitNullCharactersValidator

Tags: python, django, validation

When I run my django app raise this error, i this this is an error related with versions, Im using python 3.6 and Django 1.11.10:

```
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view
      File "/home/eddy/Documentos/apps/django/multas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework_swagger/views.py", line 3, in <module>
        from rest_framework.renderers import CoreJSONRenderer
      File "/home/eddy/Documentos/apps/django/multas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 22, in <module>
        from rest_framework import VERSION, exceptions, serializers, status
      File "/home/eddy/Documentos/apps/django/multas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 29, in <module>
        from rest_framework.fields import get_error_detail, set_value
      File "/home/eddy/Documentos/apps/django/multas/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 15, in <module>
        from django.core.validators import (
    ImportError: cannot import name 'ProhibitNullCharactersValidator'
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <_pydev_bundle.pydev_monkey._NewThreadStartupWithTrace object at 0x7f7046347f98>
```

this is my requirements.txt

```
cx-Oracle==6.2
Django==1.11.10
pytz==2017.3
django-settings-export ==1.2.1
Pillow==5.1.0
zeep==2.5.0
pylokit==0.8.1
reportlab==3.5.5
templated-docs==0.3.1
django-debug-toolbar==1.9.1
djangorestframework-datatables==0.4.0
rarfile==3.0
django-rest-swagger==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.7.3
```

in this code raise error:

```
from django.core.validators import (
    EmailValidator, MaxLengthValidator, MaxValueValidator, MinLengthValidator,
    MinValueValidator, ProhibitNullCharactersValidator, RegexValidator,
    URLValidator, ip_address_validators
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ProhibitNullCharactersValidator`  is **New in Django 2.0**.

See [Django 2.0 release notes validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.0/#validators)

Also Django REST framework `3.12.0` and higher does't support `Django 1.11` anymore. See [Requirements](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework/3.12.0/) of `djangorestframework 3.12.0`

You **have to upgrade** your `Django` or **downgrade** Django REST Framework to **3.11.2**